# PHPMailer outlook view in browser

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hi to any PHPMailer expert.
Being using the mailer and works like a charm!
I have received mails several from various organizations and I get a "**View in Browser**" option.
I would like to add that same functionality to my mails. I have googled endlessly without success :(
Can anyone point me in the write direction or post the code?

As per usual your help is always appreciated.
Many thanks
Barry

[image]

Comment: You have to save the e-mail content before sending it (e.g. on a cloud server), get the link and add it to e-mail. There's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything specific to Outlook for doing this, but the normal approach to this (what I do) is to make the same message available as a web page as part of your sending process. On my own system it uses exactly the same mechanism that's used to preview mailings before sending.

So when you have some HTML that you use to generate your email message, do the same thing but render it as a web page directly. If you're using PHPMailer you would do whatever you normally do to build a message and put your content in the `Body` property and send it, but just output it to the browser instead.

Comment: I think it has something to do with possibly sending as or attaching  mhtml as opposed to html ?

Comment: I’ve never heard of mhtml, but if it’s a proprietary thing for outlook, it would probably break in other clients. The underlying problem is that an email message does not inherently have a URL, so it makes little difference what’s in the message.

Comment: Synchro Thanks for feedback; what do you mean by; output it to the browser instead? Thanks

Comment: When you generate your message body, you normally send it as an email – but it’s just HTML so you can just `écho` the same thing to deliver it to a browser instead. So you need to create an endpoint that serves the same content from your web site, and provide a link to that in the email.